# Access a variable defined in a js file using an angular directive in a different file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a js file to consume a webservice and here i define an array that i want to use in a ng-repeat directive.
this is what i have at the moment

html

```
<article ng-repeat="article in scopeArticles">
    <h1 class="content">content is {{article.title}} </h1>
    <img src="{{article.imgSource}}" href="{{article.source}}"/>
    <p>{{article.description}}</p>
</article>
```

js file

```
  var articles = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=001034455"
    }).then(function (data) {
        $.each(data.articles, function (key, value) {
            articles.push({
                title: value.title,
                description: value.description,
                source: value.url,
                imgSource: value.urlToImage,
                date: value.publishedAt
            });

        })

    })

});
```

Comment: `scopeArticles` and `articles` are different variables!

Comment: Also it is better use `$http` service (inside a controller) instead of `$.ajax` to make it look and work in a more angularjs-way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to forget a bit about jQuery while working with AngularJS. 
Use [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to fetch your data. And your html will not work without controller.

See the working example below (don't' forget to add your API key to the URL):

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller("Ctrl",function($scope, $http){
      var ctrl = this; 
      
      ctrl.articles = [];
      
      $http.get(
        'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey='
        )
      .then(function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response.data.articles, function(value){
                ctrl.articles.push({
                    title: value.title,
                    description: value.description,
                    source: value.url,
                    imgSource: value.urlToImage,
                    date: value.publishedAt
                });
            });
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as $ctrl">

<article ng-repeat="article in $ctrl.articles">
    <h1 class="content">content is {{article.title}} </h1>
    <img ng-src="{{article.imgSource}}" href="{{article.source}}"/>
    <p>{{article.description}}</p>
</article>

 
</body>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm learning html and jquery and i decided to add angularjs so thank you for your help